# How to verify a file exists on the local file system using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am using the api test in UFT to transfer a file via FTP, if the file doesn't exist on the local file system when I try to transfer it then an empty file with the original name expected is created and transferred via ftp.  Is there a way to return an error rather than just copy a blank file via ftp?  I am open to using custom code to check the files existence before trying to copy although it would be better if UFT would just return an error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: i found my own answer :-)  For Api tests

In the Toolbox -->File -->File Exists

Answer (score 3):

Please Try This One Hope It Would Help

```
Set fileSystemObj = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

'To check if the given file present'

```
MyFile = "C:\TestFile.txt"

If fileSystemObj.FileExists(MyFile) then

    Msgbox  "File is present" & MyFile

Else

    Msgbox "File does not present" & MyFile

End If
```

'To check if the given folder present'

```
MyFolder = "C:\TestFolder"

If fileSystemObj.FolderExists(MyFolder) Then

    Msgbox  "Folder is present" & MyFolder

Else

    Msgbox "Folder does not present" & MyFolder

End If
```

'To check if the given Drive present'

```
MyDrive ="D:\" 

If fileSystemObj.DriveExists(MyDrive) then 

    Msgbox  "Drive is present" & MyDrive

Else

    Msgbox "Drive does not present" & MyDrive

End If

Set fileSystemObj = Nothing
```